# Remote desktop and clipdiary

Tags: remote-desktop, clipboard, citrix

How do I disable the local clipdiary from copying information from the remote session but still work when using local machine.

Comment: Citrix is probably keeping the local and remote clipboards in sync. This is frequently a desirable feature. See if Citrix's options allow you to disable that.

Comment: So that is a security flaw in the remote session as users can paste information from remote to local machine inadvertently and remote session would not know about it?

Comment: I don't know that I'd say it's a flaw. Clipboards are inherently insecure. Once you or something into it, you pretty much lose control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use "one-way" clipboard

By default the clipboard works both ways. Into the published app/desktop and out of the published desktop.

But you can tweak this.

- For XenApp before v7.0: You can make the clipboard READ ONLY for the app. So you can paste INTO the published app/desktop but not copy out of it. This [feature has existed since 2009 and is done via Windows registry.](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2009/10/23/how-awesome-is-hdx-part-3-of-3-secure-clipboard-control/) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/GOhMP).)

  - Namely: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Citrix\wfshell\Virtual Clipboard\ReadOnly` -> DWORD `1`
- For XenApp versions starting newer than v7.0 but older than v7.6: No idea.
- For XenApp v7.6 and later: You can FILTER a direction. This is a new [XenApp 7.6 feature from 2015](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2015/03/19/xendesktop-flipping-security-model-upside-down/). (Archived [here](https://archive.is/e5Dl5).)

  - There is a largeish [eDocs entry on this](http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-6/xad-policies-article/xad-policies-settings-wrapper/xad-policies-settings-ica.html). (Archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160404121334/http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/7-6/xad-policies-article/xad-policies-settings-wrapper/xad-policies-settings-ica.html).)

Note: I work with Citrix a lot, but I have never tried this feature, so I can't offer hands-on-experience for it.

### Further reading

- Similar question on Security Stack Exchange, 2012-04-02, [*What is the threat of having the clipboard enabled on Citrix and other rdp?*](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13389/what-is-the-threat-of-having-the-clipboard-enabled-on-citrix-and-other-rdp)
- Carl Stalhood is always helpful: Citrix Policies, Section [*Additional Policy Settings*](http://www.carlstalhood.com/citrix-policy-settings/#additional) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/t2NYu#selection-2737.0-2737.26).)

Comment: Don't think so. Open another question for this if you need more input on this.